# filter dates using pandas from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column of dates. I need to filter out those dates that fall between **today's** date and **end of the current month**. If the dates fall between these dates then the next column showns "Y"

| Date | Column |
| --- | --- |
| 01/02/2021 |  |
| 03/02/2021 |  |
| 31/03/2021 | Y |
| 01/03/2021 |  |
| 07/03/2021 | Y |
| 08/03/2021 | Y |

Since today's date is 07/03/2021 three dates fall between 07/03/2021 and 31/03/2021.

Comment: Is the column labelled `Column` to be added, or does that column already exist in the data frame?

Comment: That's a new Column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert into `datetime` column using specific time format and compare with `today`'s timestamp

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format='%d/%m/%Y')

today = pd.to_datetime('today').normalize()
end_of_month = today + pd.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd(1)

df['Column'] = np.where((df.Date >= today) & (df.Date <= end_of_month), 'Y', '')
```

Output

```
        Date Column
0 2021-02-01       
1 2021-02-03       
2 2021-03-31      Y
3 2021-03-01       
4 2021-03-07      Y
5 2021-03-08      Y
6 2021-04-02
```

Comment: Good answer, but OP requires between today and the "end of the current month". This includes future dates beyond the current month.

Comment: Totally missed that. Thanks for reminding @mhawke

Comment: df.date column is in 44270 (float64) format and with pd.to_datetime it gets converted to 01-01-1970 00:00:00 . It does not take any format

Comment: With the data that you provided, the code works. With `float64` format it cannot look like the sample data given. I can't help until you provide correct data.